# Route 53 Subdomains and API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I have a domain hosted through Route 53 called *foo.com* and all is good.  I have both NS and SOA records created in Route 53:

```
foo.com. NS
ns-1609.awsdns-09.co.uk. 
ns-431.awsdns-53.com. 
ns-1071.awsdns-05.org. 
ns-662.awsdns-18.net.

foo.com. SOA
ns-1609.awsdns-09.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com.
```

We also segment our platforms by account.  So, we have an AWS subaccount that supports our DEV environment (following the AWS document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-routing-traffic-for-subdomains.html).  So, within our foo.com hosted zone, we also have an entry:

```
devapi.foo.com. NS
ns-3476.awsdns-09.co.uk. 
ns-2341.awsdns-76.com. 
ns-3245.awsdns-56.org. 
ns-294.awsdns-67.net.
```

Within our AWS DEV account, we have a *devapi.foo.com* hosted zone with the exact same NS record:

```
devapi.foo.com. NS
ns-3476.awsdns-09.co.uk. 
ns-2341.awsdns-76.com. 
ns-3245.awsdns-56.org. 
ns-294.awsdns-67.net.
```

along with a SOA record and an A record that points at the DEV API Gateway:

```
devapi.foo.com. A  ALIAS f-8wdjr4hvgh.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.
```

where *f-8wdjr4hvgh.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.* is the domain name of the API Gateway.

I have a custom domain mapping for *devapi.foo.com*

Unfortunately, in all of this, *devapi.foo.com* is not pingable/routable.  If you ping it, it returns an IP address but a Request timeout for icmp_seq* ...

If I use https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/ for *devapi.foo.com*, I get green check marks but I believe that all that is telling me is that the domain name is resolvable.

Thoughts on what I am missing?

Followup: The issue was with the Custom Domain Mapping and Base Path.

Comment: API gateway doesn't allow pings (nearly everything in AWS blocks ICMP by default). Is something else not working?

Comment: I can access the services deployed through the API Gateway using the AWS-generated endpoints.  However, I cannot access the services using the *devapi.foo.com* URL (403 forbidden error), such an invocation is not even registered within the API Gateway Cloudwatch logs which leads me to believe that the problem lies with how I sent up the Route 53 hosted zones.  I can resolve the AWS-generated DNS name for the API Gateway (the alias in the A record) in that it gives me back an IP address (I can ping *f-8wdjr4hvgh.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com* and an IP address is returned).

Comment: Doh! My bad, everything is configured correctly except how I have the Custom Domain Mapping.  I will close the question but leave it here because I believe it offers a good example of how to do subdomain hosting when you have DEV, TEST, etc in different subdomains/accounts.

Comment: @PerryHoekstra You can answer your own question with more details if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a problem where I went to setup a record that mapped my custom sub-domain to my API Gateway. When I went to select the actual endpoint I got a red warning/error message saying "cannot retrieve endpoint suggestions"

The instructions for setting everything up are here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-api-gateway.html

Before doing what I was trying to do, the prerequisites (stated on the linked page) were:

1. An API Gateway API that has a custom domain name, such as api.example.com, that matches the name of the Route 53 record that you want to create.
2. A registered domain name. You can use Amazon Route 53 as your domain registrar, or you can use a different registrar.
3. Route 53 as the DNS service for the domain. If you register your domain name by using Route 53, we automatically configure Route 53 as the DNS service for the domain.

I realized I had not done step #1. This needs to be done via the API Gateway interface, not the Route 53 interface. If you haven't done this for the domain yet (not the sub-domain, but the domain) you may need to do some work to setup a certificate for the domain. This involves placing what looks to be a sort of magic key entry in your domain registry (using Route 53 or whatever you used to register your domain) so that Amazon knows you own the domain.

Once this custom domain has been setup (again, in the API Gateway section, not Route 53), then I was able to create a record in Route 53 and my API Gateway endpoint was now detected for selection.